# Python TkInter: Rightmost column and bottommost row value for grid attribute?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, grid

I want to create a button and have it appear on the rightmost side of the frame. However, I don't know what values to enter for the column parameter in the grid attribute.

I know that in pack, we can use side and assign it to RIGHT, but I want to use grid to do this.

Thank you so much!

**Edit:**

My code:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("FoodU")
root.geometry("1600x2560+0+0")


#statusbar BEGIN

statusbar = Frame(root, bg="black")
statusbar.pack(fill=X, side=TOP)


row, column = root.grid_size()
profile = Button(statusbar, text="Profile", fg="white", highlightbackground="black")
profile.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="e", padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=4, ipady=3)


#statusbar END


root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: why not a column one greater than all of the other columns?

Comment: @BryanOakley But what if there are no other elements?

Comment: You should type your code (or copy/paste) in instead of posting a picture. That way I can copy/paste it from StackOverflow. You do this by indenting each line by 4 spaces to mark it as code (or 8 to indent once, 12 for 2 indents, etc...)

Comment: @PriyaParashar: If there are no other elements, then use row 0 column 0. You can use the `sticky` option to have your widget stick to the bottom right corner of the space it was allocated. Though, if you literally only have a single widget, I would use `place` for this specific task. The problem is, there are very few good general rules that apply in all circumstances. The proper tool depends greatly on what other widgets will be on the screen, and how they should related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the grids size which will be one higher in either dimension than what you have already gridded. Something along the lines of:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(text='Hello').grid(row=1, column=1)
row, column = win.grid_size()
tk.Entry().grid(row=row, column=column)
win.mainloop()
```

**@EDIT**

If you would like to justify the text within the `Button()` to the right you would use `Button(text='Click Me!', justify='right').grid(row=row, column=column)` You can see other such methods for Buttons at:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

If you would like the Button to move with the right side of the screen when you resize the window, then you would need to both make the button "stick" to that side, and make the column/row have a weight where it will resize with the window:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(text='Hello', justify='right').grid(row=1, column=1)
row, column = win.grid_size()
tk.Button(text='Bottom corner').grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nsew') # you could just use 'e' to make it stick to the right side
win.columnconfigure(column, weight=1) # this sets the column to resize with the window
win.mainloop()
```

If this helped solve your problem, I'd appreciate you clicking that green check mark :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But how do I align the button to the right when it is the only element present?

Comment: @PriyaParashar I do not understand. The button should be on the right side of the screen already, no? Are you asking about aligning text *within* the button?

Comment: Thanks so much for the edit! That did make it a lot clearer. And yes, I wanted to align the entire button to the right, not just the text. I used the code you mentioned, but it still doesn't work. I've edited my code and output into my question.

Comment: @PTH This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can grid it to the last column of your windows and use sticky:

```
button.grid(root, row=0, column=n, sticky='e')
```

Sticky takes a string of which cardinal direction it has to stick to, with 'e' being east, so right side